# Three Minkowski functionals resulting the same

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $(X,\|\|)$ a normed vector space over $K$ and $E\subset X$ convex and absorbing. Let $p_E(x)=\inf_{x\in tE}\{t>0\}$, $E_1=\{x\in X:p_E(x)<1\}$ and $E_2=\{x\in X:p_E(x)\le 1\}$. I want to prove that:
$$
p_{E_1}=p_E=p_{E_2}
$$
I really don't get it at all. I've only came up with $p_{E_1}(x)\le p_E(x)\le p_{E_2}(x)$, since $E_1\subset E\subset E_2$. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: When dealing with Minkowsky functionals, we don't need to consider normed spaces (note that $E$ is not closed, open, etc..., i.e., it does not care about the topology of $X$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, since the Minkowski functionals are defined by infimums and $E_1\subseteq E\subseteq E_2$, we have $p_{E_2}\leq p_E\leq p_{E_1}$.

We need to use the fact that Minkowski functionals are sublinear: Given $E\subseteq X$ convex and absorbing, we have
$$p_E(x+y)\leq p_E(x)+p_E(y)\qquad\text{and}\qquad p_E(tx)=tp_E(x)$$
for all $x,y\in X$, $t\geq 0$. This is standard. In fact, this implies that $E_1$ and $E_2$ as you defined are indeed convex and absorbing, so we can also consider their Minkowski functionals

Let's show $p_{E_1}\leq p_{E_2}$. Let $x\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$. By definition of $p_{E_2}(x)$, there exists $t>0$ with $t<p_{E_2}(x)+\epsilon$ and $x\in tE_2$, i.e., $t^{-1}x\in E_2$ and thus $p_E(t^{-1}x)\leq 1$.

By sublinearity of $p_E$ (two times), we have $p_E(x)\leq t<t+\epsilon$, so $p_E((t+\epsilon)^{-1}x)<1$, thus $(t+\epsilon)^{-1}x\in E_1$ and hence $p_{E_1}((t+\epsilon)^{-1}x)\leq 1$, and now by sublinearity of $p_{E_1}$ we obtain
$$p_{E_1}(x)\leq t+\epsilon<p_{E_2}(x)+2\epsilon$$
Letting $\epsilon\to 0$, we obtain $p_{E_1}(x)\leq p_{E_2}(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! And how would you show that $E_1$ is absorbing?

Comment: Ok I think I see it in your proof: Let $x\in X$, so given any $\epsilon>0\;\;\exists t>0$  s.t. $x\in tE$. So taking $\tilde t=t+\epsilon$ we get that $x\in \tilde t E_1$

Comment: @Arnulf You are right. That was basically a comment: "Using the sublinearity of $p_E$, you can show that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are absorbing and convex", and I was not really trying to prove it. But as you correctly noted, the proof that $E_1$ is absorbing is "hidden" in the solution :)